# How to use Spring data Jpa fetch simple string result?

Tags: sql, spring-data

How to use Spring data Jpa fetch simple string result ?
I use Spring data Jpa can only get the result if an object or a set of objects.
There lots information I don`t want to get, 
Can I use @Query to get some simple String result.

Answer (score 0):

Normally `@Query` should return Object (or List/Set of them) in case of queries like this one:

```
@Query("select u.name from User u where u.lastname = :lastname")
List<Object> findByLastname(@Param("lastname") String lastName);
```

But you can create custom implementation for your repository(see [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations))

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
public List<String> findUserNamesByLastname(String lastName) {
    return (List<String>) (Object) userRepository.findByLastname(String lastName);
}
```