# Converting List of childs to List of parents in one line

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, polymorphism, java-8

Converting `List` of `Banana` to `List` of `Fruit` ...

```
public class Fruit { }

public class Banana extends Fruit { }

public List<Banana> allBananas() {
    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Banana(), new Banana()));
}
```

... before returning I have to do following two-steps-casting:

```
public List<Fruit> getFruits() {
    List<? extends Fruit> fruits = (List<? extends Fruit>) allBananas();
    return (List<Fruit>) fruits;
}
```

To avoid the intermediate step it can be done as:

```
public List<Fruit> getFruits() {
    return allBananas().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

But in this case I have to create new `List` object which is not so good in terms of performance.

I think I don't understand something and maybe doing it wrong.
I want to know is my code fully correct and safe? If so - is there a better way to cast? If not - what is wrong and can be improved?

Comment: Your cast in the first version is unsafe anyway. Fundamentally a `List<Banana>` is *not* a `List<Fruit>`. We have no idea what the context is here - it could well be that what you should *actually* do is just change the signature to `List<? extends Fruit>` getFruit()`

Comment: Is it technically legal to cast `allBananas()` of initial type `List<Banana>` to `(List<? extends Fruit>)` when `Banana extends Fruit`? @JonSkeet

Comment: Something like `Dog and Cat extends Animal` and cast `Dog` to `Cat`. I think it is illogical. @JonSkeet

Comment: @JonSkeet in some cases changing the signature makes return type too wide like in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29984452/4556720) my answer to another question.

Comment: @ytterrr: I don't see how that answer is relevant to my suggestion...

Comment: @JonSkeet I mean `List<? extends Object> findUserNamesByLastname` in that answer.

Comment: But here I'm suggesting `List<? extends Fruit>`, so it's still fairly specific. Fundamentally though you still haven't told us the context. Do you want a view on the existing list, or a *copy* of the existing list?

Comment: @JonSkeet I think _view_ of the existing list is preferable in most cases because we don't have to create another `List` (at least in terms of performance)

Comment: Right - so what would you expect to happen if someone called `view.add(new Apple())` to that list? They can't do that if you've presented a `List<? extends Fruit>`, so that's okay - but if you've presented a `List<Fruit>` then they can, at which point either you break the original `List<Banana>` or you have to detect it at execution time and throw an exception... and you haven't talked about what you need for *any* of this in your question, making it unanswerable.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you for great explanation. It is a pity that I can not accept comment in this site.

Comment: Well it's only a comment because it can't be an answer - because the question isn't clear enough *to* answer. If you update your question so that it's answerable, I can add an answer...

Comment: @JonSkeet the question was updated. I think now it's answerable.

Comment: Well, it still doesn't say what you actually want - but I've answered with lots of options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what you want to achieve.

If you're happy to create a *copy* of the list, then I'd just use something like:

```
public List<Fruit> getFruits() {
    return new ArrayList<>(allBananas());
}
```

That's now independent of the original list, so the caller can then do what they want with it. (If they modify any of the existing bananas, those modifications will be seen of course, but that's not a change to the list itself.)

However, it sounds like you don't want to copy the list, which means you effectively want some kind of view on the existing list. The tricky bit here is doing that safely. Your casting code is *not* safe:

```
// Don't do this!
public List<Fruit> getFruits() {
    List<? extends Fruit> fruits = (List<? extends Fruit>) allBananas();
    return (List<Fruit>) fruits;
}
```

Here's why it's broken:

```
List<Banana> bananas = allBananas();
List<Fruit> fruit = getFruits();
System.out.println(bananas == fruits); // Same list
fruit.add(new Apple()); // This is fine, right?
Banana banana = bananas.get(0); // This should be fine, right?
```

You'll actually end up with an invalid cast exception in the last line, because you've basically violated type safety in your `getFruits()` method. A `List<Banana>` is *not* a `List<Fruit>`.

Your safe options are:

- Change the method return type to `List<? extends Fruit>` at which point you don't need any casting:

  ```
  public List<? extends Fruit> getFruits() {
      return allBananas();
  }
  ```

  Now the caller can't add to the list (except `null`), but *can* remove items from the list.
- Use an implementation of `List<Fruit>` which permits additions, but checks at execution time that each item is a `Banana`, e.g.

  ```
  return (List<Fruit>) Collections.checkedList(allBananas(), Banana.class);
  ```
- Return an unmodifiable view of the list, e.g.

  ```
  public List<Fruit> getFruits() {
      return Collections.unmodifiableList(allBananas());
  }
  ```

Which option is appropriate (including copying) is very context-dependent.

Comment: To your second safe option, using `Collections.checkedList(list, Banana.class)` would ensure at runtime that only Bananas are added to the list. The unchecked casts are still necessary, though, since the static type system doesn't know anything about the runtime checking.

Answer (score 3):

You can just do

```
public List<Fruit> getFruits() {
    return new ArrayList<>(allBananas());
}
```

Note that your casting example is unsafe, and you'll get compilation warnings. This is because a `List<Banana>` is *not* a `List<Fruit>`.

If a `List<Banana>` *was* a `List<Fruit>`, you would be able to add *any* `Fruit` to it, which you clearly shouldn't:

```
// won't compile, because List<Banana> is not a List<Fruit>
List<Fruit> fruit = (List<Fruit>) myBananaList();

// if it did compile (or if you do it with casting), this would "work"
fruit.add(new Apple()); // doesn't make sense

// but if something uses same Banana list as a Banana list
// and gets an Apple instead of a banana, it will cause a class cast exception
Banana banana = bananas.get(index);
```

So casting `List<Banana>` to `List<Fruit>` is always technically incorrect, and that's why Java won't let you do it directly.

Your intermediate cast to `List<? extends Fruit>` is a little misleading.  In your case it happens to work because of [the way Java generics are implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens), but it's not really any better than doing something like this:

```
// DON'T DO THIS!
public List<Fruit> getFruits_bad() {
    Object fruits = allBananas();
    return (List<Fruit>) fruits;
}
```

It compiles for the same reason the code below compiles, but this one will fail at runtime because type erasure won't apply:

```
// DON'T DO THIS EITHER
Object obj="a string";
Integer i=(Integer) obj;
```

Comment: I think you meant `Integer i = (Integer) obj;`

Comment: Not quite. `obj` instead of `blah`. :). Sorry :).

Comment: @artaxerxe thanks again. I obviously had `(Integer) blah;` in my original code and double-click edited the wrong word trying to change `blah` to `obj`. No need to apologize for being helpful :-)

Answer (score 3):

Apart from changing the method signature to `List<? extends Fruit>`, you can use `Collections.unmodifiableList` to get a read-only `List<Fruit>` view of a `List<Banana>`:

```
public List<Fruit> getFruits() {
    List<Banana> bananas = getBananas();
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(bananas);
}
```

Both `unmodifiableList` and declaring the method as `List<? extends Fruit>` serve the same goal -- keep the client of this method from adding an orange to a list of bananas.

Comment: or `return Collections.unmodifiableList(allBananas());` to satisfy "in one line" :-)